# Linked Dynamic Radio Buttons HTML Javascript

Tags: javascript, radio-button, dhtml

All,

Have used this site a few times before and had some great replies so hopefully someone can help again. I want a set of radio buttons, so that when you click a button - you get another set below it. Then again, when you click one of the 2nd set of buttons, you'll get a third etc. Currently I have the following:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>My Wizard</title>

    <script language="javascript">

    function Display(question) {
            h1=document.getElementById("yes");
            h2=document.getElementById("no");
            h3=document.getElementById("dk");
            h4=document.getElementById("yes2");

                if (question=="yes") h1.style.display="block";
                    else h1.style.display="none";
                if (question=="no") h2.style.display="block";
                    else h2.style.display="none";
                if (question=="dk") h3.style.display="block";
                    else h3.style.display="none";
                if (question=="yes2") h4.style.display="block";
                    else h4.style.display="none";
                                }
    </script>


</head>

<body>

    <hr>
        <form name="form1">
        <p>Do you like the colour blue?</p>

            <input type="radio" name="type" value="yes" checked
            onClick="Display('yes');">
            Yes

            <input type="radio" name="type" value="no"
            onClick="Display('no');">
            No

            <input type="radio" name="type" value="dk"
            onClick="Display('dk');">
            Don't know

<br>

<div ID="yes" style="display:none;">

    <hr>
        <p>Do you like the colour red?</p>

            <input type="radio" name="type" value="yes2" checked
            onClick="Display('yes2')">
            Yes

            <input type="radio" name="type" value="no2"
            onClick="Display('no2');">
            No

</div>

<div ID="yes2" style="display:none">
I want this to appear beneath the 2nd set of buttons, not replacing it!
</div>

<div ID="no2" style="display:none">
test2
</div>


<div ID="no" style="display:none">
<b>this is my no box:</b>
<input type="text" name="no" size="25">
</div>

<div ID="dk" style="display:none">
<b>dk:</b>
<input type="text" name="dk" size="15">
</div>

</form>
</body>
</html>
```

So basically, i'm trying to make a little wizard - so something that will ask the user a question, and based on this - it will ask them another. I dont want to use server side applications so am trying something simple like this - but whenever the user selects an option from the 2nd set of buttons, the text which goes with it replaces the 2nd set of buttons. What am i doing wrong?

Please select 'yes' and 'yes' again to see what i mean. Any help will be appreciated!

Joe

Comment: What kind of a name is 'yes2'? It should be 'file not found'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `if` statement is wrong. You ask again and again this: `if (question=="yes") h1.style.display="block";
                    else h1.style.display="none";` and the second time if is not true, so you set the h1 to be hidden.

here is one solution:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>My Wizard</title>

<script language="javascript">

function Display(question, i) {
        h1=document.getElementById("yes");
        h2=document.getElementById("no");
        h3=document.getElementById("dk");
        h4=document.getElementById("yes2");

        if(i==1){
            if (question=="yes") h1.style.display="block";
                else h1.style.display="none";
            if (question=="no") h2.style.display="block";
                else h2.style.display="none";
        }else if(i==2){
            if (question=="dk") h3.style.display="block";
                else h3.style.display="none";
            if (question=="yes2") h4.style.display="block";
                else h4.style.display="none";
        }
}
</script>


</head>

<body>

    <hr>
    <form name="form1">
    <p>Do you like the colour blue?</p>

        <input type="radio" name="type" value="yes" checked
        onClick="Display('yes', 1);">
        Yes

        <input type="radio" name="type" value="no"
        onClick="Display('no', 1);">
        No

        <input type="radio" name="type" value="dk"
        onClick="Display('dk', 1);">
        Don't know

<br>

<div ID="yes" style="display:none;">

<hr>
    <p>Do you like the colour red?</p>

        <input type="radio" name="type" value="yes2" checked
        onClick="Display('yes2', 2)">
        Yes

        <input type="radio" name="type" value="no2"
        onClick="Display('no2', 2);">
        No

</div>

<div ID="yes2" style="display:none">
I want this to appear beneath the 2nd set of buttons, not replacing it!
</div>

<div ID="no2" style="display:none">
test2
</div>


<div ID="no" style="display:none">
<b>this is my no box:</b>
<input type="text" name="no" size="25">
</div>

<div ID="dk" style="display:none">
<b>dk:</b>
<input type="text" name="dk" size="15">
</div>

</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This is exactly what I want! Thank you so much. I'm very new to Javascript so it's taking me a while. Absolutely perfect response though. Many thanks

Comment: Martin, If you click yes in the top box, then yes in the second box, then go back to the first box and click no - you get the second response box appearing beneath the first question. Is that easy to fix?

Comment: Yes. You have an if, and if that condition is met, things happen. right now you just set things to be visible, so simply add a row that hides other stuff. An almost template `if(condition){hX.style.display="block";hY.style.display="none";}else{hY.style.display="block";hX.style.display="none";}` or something like that. in general just think what you want to happen if the condition is met. Another approach is to split it into tow functions (recommended when if blocks get big)

Answer (score 1):

Radio input elements are grouped by their `name` attribute. You should assign a different name to the other sets of radio input elements.

Visual example:

```
[x] name=favColor   [ ] name=favRed
[ ] name=favColor   [x] name=favRed
[ ] name=favColor   [ ] name-favRed
```

See also: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/HTML/Element/input